# Duration of a Single-Tap and Long-Tap in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm trying to drag overlays an a map and also display an infobox if the user taps on a pin. To do so I need to measure the time between `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. To make it feel as natural as possible I would like to know what value Android uses for a Single-Tap (currently I'm using 180ms) and also for a Long-Tap.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to write the code for distinguish between `single-Tap` and `long-Tap`. Instead use `GestureDetector`. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I tried onTap() from ItemizedOverlay and it's not triggered. I assume onTouchEvent() that I need for dragging is consuming all touch events. So I don't think that GestureDetector is going to work... Maybe you misunderstood my question, cause my main problem was to distinguish between single-Tap/long-Tap and a scroll.

Comment: `GestureDetector` dosen't intercept motion events, you need to feed them to `GestureDetector` by calling `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)`. So, as long has you can get a motion event you can feed it to `GestureDetector`. The motion event is analysed by the class, and when appropriate it make callbacks to `onDoubleTap()`, `onLongPress()`, `onScroll()`, `onSingleTapConfirmed()` and some others. Maybe you should have a look at documentation in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html.

Comment: Also, you need to be sure that you return `false` from `onTouchEvent()` if you didn't use the event for something: This informs that the event wasn't consumed and can be used by others (i.e. `onTap()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android source uses 125ms for a single tap and 500ms as the long press time:

```
private static final int PRESSED_STATE_DURATION = 125;

private static final int DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 500;
```

[ViewConfiguration.java#PRESSED_STATE_DURATION](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#ViewConfiguration.0PRESSED_STATE_DURATION)

[ViewConfiguration.java#DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#ViewConfiguration.0DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT)

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to go with TAP_TIMEOUT instead of PRESSED_STATE_DURATION, which is the exact same 180ms that I'm already using.